# JWT token expiry time gets trimmed in generated token

Tags: java, date, token, jwt

I am generating a JWT token in one of my application to communicate to some third party APIs, i could create the token properly, untill  i started facing a strange issue below is how i am setting the expuration date for my token:

```
JWTClaimsSet jwtClaims = new JWTClaimsSet();
jwtClaims.setExpirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000*60*120));
jwtClaims.setCustomClaim("myobj", prepare(myobj));
JWSHeader header = new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.RS256);
header.setContentType("text/plain");
```

and just below this i do a

```
System.out.println("after :::"+jwtClaims.getExpirationTime().getTime());
```

which prints the value as: 1420636467027
however when i decode my token i am getting this value as: 1420636467 so basically the last 3 digits are getting trimmed, moreover the third party API is failing my calls on account of expired token and rightly so.
Is there anything additional which i need to do in order to avoid this situtation'
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: which library/class/code are you using for the jwtClaims variable?

Comment: also note that `Date.getTime` returns a timestamp in milliseconds since 1970 and the JWT `exp` claims contains the time in seconds

Comment: i am using com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet

Comment: which version? (see: https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/issue/35/jwtclaimsset-milliseconds-vs-seconds-issue)

Comment: currently using 2.25, trying out the newer one

Comment: Perhaps you can copy the construction approach they use for their unit test: `final Date NOW =  new Date(new Date().getTime() / 1000 * 1000); Date exp = new Date(NOW.getTime() + 1000*60*10); jwtClaims.setExpirationTime(exp);` and see if that helps with the printout? You may also print `jwtClaims.toJSONObject()` and `jwtClaims.toString()` to verify the contents.

Comment: Tried this out with no luck, the problem lies with the jwtClaims the JSON string is printing the value as JSON :{"exp":1420637448} which is the trimmed date

Comment: no, the trimmed date in `jwtClaims.toJSONObject()` is correct(!) since that's the JWT representation of the timestamp which is in seconds; but the `jwtClaims.toString()` should print a Date timestamp

Comment: also note that your timestamp (the JSON variant) is correct but just expired (1:30 UTC); so using that in the JWT would could the receiving party to reject it indeed

Comment: I use nimbus-jose-jwt 2.26.1 and it puts seconds into "exp" as well and this seems to be the correct behaviour. The bug is likely on the other side.

Comment: In my POV, this is slightly better way to instantiate date: `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expireInSeconds * 1000)`. This way you avoid construction of one Date object.

Comment: Yeah may be but that doesnt address the problem mentioned, anyway i got rid of nimbusds and using spring security jwt helper classes which has a comparatively neat implementation.

Answer (score 3):

All the times in JWT token like issued at time(iat), not before time(nbf) and expiration time(exp) are supposed to be measured in seconds since 1/1/1970. Since you are specifying time in milliseconds, that might be causing issues at the server end when the server cracks open your JWT token. Just start using time in seconds. Hopefully that shall resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When adding time with milliseconds, use a long value. This should resolve it:

```
.expirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 720000L))
```